# Getting Row and Colum Values in OpenPyXl

Tags: python, pycharm, openpyxl

I'm trying to format data from some excel sheets. I'm brand new to openpyxl and a little new to python, but I'd say fairly experienced with other languages such as C and Java.
I was wondering if, with the way I'm looping through the cells, I could somehow get the index of the row and column iterations?

An example in Java:

```
for (int row = 2; row < 5; row++) {
   for (int col = 2; col < 3; col++) {
      // at this exact spot, we know the index of the ROW in row and COLUMN in col
```

So, in the following code where I doing `print(cell.value)`, is there a variable of some sort that can tell me the index of the row and column?

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook('reviews-sample.xlsx')

print(wb.sheetnames)

while True:
    sheet = input("Enter exact name of sheet to use: ")
    if sheet in wb.sheetnames:
        break
    else:
        print("Sheet name does not exist!")

ws = wb[sheet]  # user-chosen worksheet to get data from

for row in ws.iter_rows(2, 5, 2, 3):  # min_row, max_row, min_col, max_col (B2:B5)
    for cell in row:
        print(cell.value)

wb.close()
```

Comment: Are you looking for `enumerate()`? Mind you that, coming from C or Java, you often think you need the index to access something, when in well-written Python, you probably don't. But of course there are times when you do, and in those cases iterating over `for n, x in enumerate(my_iterable)` is the right way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `row` and `column` attributes of the `cell`. Note that it's 1-based. So the upper left cell A1 has a column and row index of 1.

The [documentation](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.cell.cell.html) is worth checking out.

While not necessarily pythonic, in my experience, it is just easier to use conventional for-loops to access cells.

Cells can be read or created using a `worksheet`'s `cell` method:

```py
top_left_cell = ws.cell(row=1, column=1, value="We just set A1's value to this")
top_left_cell = ws.cell(1, 1, "This does the same, just without kw-args")
top_left_cell = ws.cell(1, 1) # This returns the cell without settings its value
print(top_left_cell.value) # "This does the same, just without kw-args"
top_left_cell.value = "Change its value with its value attribute"
```

In Python, you can print out the relevant documentation by entering `help(name)` into the REPL. For example, try:

```py
help(openpyxl)
help(openpyxl.load_workbook)
help(openpyxl.worksheet)
help(openpyxl.cell.cell)
help(str)
```

It works if you enter a variable name, too:

```py
help(wb)
help(ws)
help(cell)
```